# Does Hyper-V support using the host mouse cursor instead of the client's

Tags: hyper-v

Using an Ubuntu client on Hyper-V in Windows 10 appears to respond equally fast to my mouse movement however the display of the cursor is much slower than the host OS.  It causes it to appear to jump around a bit.

If possible, I would like to keep the host mouse always visible.  Ideally, I would be able to mouse over the console of the Hyper-V client without losing sight of the mouse cursor.  Then, with the client being the active window, the host mouse cursor would still be in view.

Is there a way to achieve this with Hyper-V on a Windows 10 host?

Comment: Funny enough, I'm searching for how to do exactly the opposite (by default the mouse cursor moves transparently between the guest OS and the host, instead of being "captured", and this is causing me problems).

Comment: Which guest OS are you using?  I've since abandoned Hyper-V completely due to this lag and have gone with 2 PCs using a KVM.

Comment: This behavior is noted on all of my VMs, including Linux and even Android. I tried everything, disabled "Enhanced Session" and whatnot, but to no avail. Just installed VMWare Player and it seems to work great though.